# Why there are 2 ways to create a task in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I'm currently writing a gradle script to automate some builds. However it seems that there are 2 ways to create tasks. What should I take and why are there different types in first place?

```
task copy(type: Copy, group: "Custom", description: "Copies sources to the dest directory") {
    from "src"
    into "dest"
}
```

vs

```
tasks.register("gutenTag", Greeting) {
    group = 'Welcome'
    description = 'Produces a German greeting'
    message = 'Guten Tag'
    recipient = 'Welt'
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first is the (one of the) older methods of adding a task to a build

The second is using register, which enables task configuration avoidance

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html

That is; the task is only configured if the task is used in the build